# Project Euler 97

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve the Project Euler #97 problem. I don't want to look on the web because they give directly the solution.

Here's the exercise :

> The first known prime found to exceed one million digits was
> discovered in 1999, and is a Mersenne prime of the form 2^6972593−1;
> it contains exactly 2,098,960 digits. Subsequently other Mersenne
> primes, of the form 2^p−1, have been found which contain more digits.
>
> However, in 2004 there was found a massive non-Mersenne prime which
> contains 2,357,207 digits: 28433×2^7830457+1.
>
> Find the last ten digits of this prime number.

So, I tried this :

```
public static void main(String []args){ 
        BigInteger i = new BigInteger("28433")
                          .multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(Math.pow(2, 7830457)))
                          .add(new BigInteger("1")));
        
        String s = i.toString();
        System.out.println(s.substring(s.length()-10, s.length()));
     }
```

Obviously that does not work :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Infinity"
```

How should I approach this problem (I'm really stuck) ? (please don't give the solution, just hints)

Thanks

Comment: instead `Math.pow` use `BigInteger`'s pow method.

Comment: Instead of Math.pow or BigInteger.pow, use BigInteger.powMod. Or just use long with mod.

Comment: @PeterLawrey what is `BigInteger.powMod`?

Comment: Doing this the hard way (actually calculating 2^7830457) just isn't how this works, even if you could do it with BigIntegers. I'll give you a hint: the last digit of 2^7830457 is two. I did not use any calculator to get this result. Think about how i did it, then maybe you get an idea how to calculate the last 10 digits without actually calculating the whole result.

Comment: @tintinmj Sorry it is BigInteger.modPow It calculates the power of something mod another values and completes much faster as it only needs the lowest portion based on the mod.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a problem where you want the answer mod 10^10 (the last ten digits)

You can calculate powers faster by using powers of two. e.g.  x*x = x^2, and x^2 * x^2 = x^4 and so on. 7 830 457 = 0b11101110111101110111001 is 2^23 + 2^22 + 2^21 + 2^19 ... 2^0 so it is  x^(2^23) * x^(2^22) * x(2^21) * x ^(2^19) * ... x  You have to perform each operation mod 10^10 to avoid overflow.  You can the multiply this by the first constant and add 1.

Using this approach you can calculate in O(log N) where N is the power.

The key function which will do most of the work for you is [BigInteger.modPow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29) It is designed to calculate large powers efficiently but only calculating the lowest portion of a number (based on the mod chosen)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in calculating 2^7830457

they want the last 10 digits so that means the number mod 10000000000

according to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

ab mod n = ((a mod n)*(b mod n))mod n

so you can calculate 2^7830457 using multiplication in a loop where you take modulus after each multiplication

**edit :** recursive multiplication would be faster

```
    public static long pow1(int a,long b,long n){
        if (b==1)return a%n;
        if (b%2==1){
            return (pow1(a,(b-1)/2,n)*a)%n;
        }
        else{
            return (pow1(a,b/2,n))%n;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a factor missing in the recursive code

```
def pow1(a,b,n):
    if (b==1):
        return a%n
    if (b%2==1):
        return (pow1(a,(b-1)//2,n)*pow1(a,b//2,n)*a)%n
    else:
        return (pow1(a,b//2,n)*pow1(a,b//2,n))%n
```

Answer (score 0):

My method was to calculate 2^7830457 mod 10000000000 using successive squaring algoritm, multiplying the result by 28433 and adding one.  Well within excel's capability.